# Which Method Do I Need To Choose For Fetching Large Data?

Tags: javascript, async-await, xmlhttprequest, fetch

My problem is that I've a large number of data (Over 50k), and I've to map it with DOM with the help of vanilla javascript (ES). Sometimes pages gets crashed while data is loading. What should I choose async/await or promises? Also which method would be better either XHR or Fetch method. Or I should use some third party library? That is big problem for me because sometimes it shows the data after an interval but sometimes pages is crashed. Can anyone explain here?

Comment: “async/await or promises?” - they are the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would look at the value gained out of really mapping 50K items to a single web page. Look at loading data on-emand in sets as users are scrolling through items - or some filtering mechanism to apply to the data before loading it.

If you really have to load so much data into a page - then look at loading it in chunks - or to optimize your code so that less strain is put on the browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).